# DENY direct download of file using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.doc` and `.zip` files in download directory on my server. 
whoever visit my site page (`download-file.php)` only those user should be able to download these files and other should not.

I am trying to achieve above but no luck...

I am still able to put direct file address (`http://example.com/sample.doc`) in browser and I am able to download which I don't want..even someone else giving link to above file on any website then also download should not happen.

Could any one please share some idea..how i should achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, you can include these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
# you can add whatever extensions you want routed to your php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(doc|zip|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /download-file.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

Then in your `download-file.php`, you can display whatever you need to display and the download link, which your php script can just immediately serve the file using [php's readfile() (see link for examples)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: This will work if file is directly accessed, but not when the same file is being viewed.

Answer (score 3):

You should disallow access to your files directory, and offer downloads only PHP driven (example with PDFs):

data/.htaccess (googled):

```
deny from all
```

download.php:

```
/* User access check here, prior to the following code */

$name = 'MyPDF.pdf';
$filename = 'data/pdf_12345.pdf';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
fpassthru($filename)
```

Of course you can set different filenames for each user and each request, like `download.php?file=MyPDF`

Comment: I think setting folder access level can do this trick. So one cannot download file. But the trick you mentioned will it deny access directly to that file like by enterling direct url `ab.com/mypdf.pdf` , and where one should place your answered code?

Comment: No, it will not automatically deny direct access - you have to do that, too. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restrict people from directly accessing your content using a method similar to the following code:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your_domain.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your_domain.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.your_domain.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.your_domain.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule .*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc)$ http://your_domain.com/no_access.php [R,NC]

This would prevent people from directly linking images, pdfs or docs from your site. Then, files with these extensions would only be able to accessed from your site.   If someone attempts to directly link or access your files, they will experience the whatever you choose for them to see (that you place in the no_access.php).

Comment: This isn't a guarantee, referers can be easily forged to get around the check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated server the easiest and in my opinion the most secure way is to store the files outside of **/var/www/**

You can for example create a folder **/var/webdocs/** and store them there.