# Codeigniter Make Download URL inaccessible in address bar

Tags: codeigniter, url, download

I am creating an application where members as well non members can download books depending upon the category of book available for both users.
I linked the books to BASE_URL/downloadPDF/11 for prompt download, passing the Id of the book, so that the file location is invisible to user.

Now what I want is no one can get the book downloaded directly pasting the book url(BASE_URL/downloadPDF/11) in browser address bar.
I tried making function private but It did not work for me.

Comment: You can achieve this with .htaccess. You may refer - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024877/deny-direct-download-of-file-using-php

Answer (score 0):

you can encode your book url. so no one can get the book downloaded directly.

Let’s say we want to encode the following string with base64:

after conversion your book url look like below string

RW5jb2RpbmcgYW5kIERlY29kaW5nIEVuY3J5cHRlZCBQSFAgQ29kZQ==

so its difficult for end user to interpret this url.

you can also decode url using base64_decode