# Is possible to get the actual link file from submit?

Tags: php, forms, download

For example, I use this form submit to download a file.

```
if(!isset($hasError) {
  //some code here.
$file_url = "http://example.com/files/download/file.pdf";
header("Expires: 0");
                  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
                  header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0', false); 
                  header("Pragma: no-cache");   
                  header("Content-type: {$content_type}");
                  header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename={$file_new_name}");
                  header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
                  flush();
                  readfile("{$file_url}");
                  exit();
}
```

With the submit form above, it will return downloadable file to save.
As I see on Chrome (Ctrl + J), the download link is not displayed. It shows only form link with action.
But is possible for visitor to know the actual link like this: "http://example.com/files/download/file.pdf".

If they can find that link, any solution to prevent this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should probably return a redirect instead of the file contents, the link in chrome will always display the url that initiated the download which in your case was the link to this script.

Comment: Unrelated side note: `"{$file_url}"`? Seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.htaccess` with `Deny from all` in `files/download/` to forbid direct access (= HTTP request) but with readfile you will can read the file.

---

NB : You need to use readfile function and stream your request (for big file) like that : https://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/ & https://www.media-division.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/

Comment: I added to .htaccess :Deny from all but after download, it returns file with wrong format. I open with Notepad, it appears text: 309 + link file.

Comment: @MinhAnh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024877/deny-direct-download-of-file-using-php ?

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer is awesome.

Comment: If you feed `readfile()` with a URL (as in the question) this restriction applies to your PHP script as well.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález .htaccess applies only for Apache (HTTP request not filesystem).

Comment: I guess you mean browser (Apache is an HTTP server). And, no, the `Deny` directive is not disabled for clients that are not browsers (what good would it make?). There's no even reliable technique to tell out a bot from a browser (that's why captchas exist).

Answer (score 1):

No, find the source link is not possible from the browser, the PHP script is trasparently sending in output the remote file content which is exactly what `readfile` function does, it reads buffers of content and echo it to the browser without leaking any info.

The browser has no ways to know anything, the user can only do some timing analysis of the response speed to know if the file is local to the server or remote, but no more than that (still don't know where "remote" is).

Comment: Thank you so much. but is possible to download that file after I denied access from .htaccess ?

Comment: Since that Apache is the web server that handles the HTTP requests, this should not be possible, because a user needs to specify the path in GET request like /path/resource.php if you deny it from htaccess then there aren't other ways to request it. This only unless a vulnerability is discovered in other accessible pages. A vulnerability like local file inclusion or trasversal path could execute the file anyway through another vulnerable script.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page for readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) says (emphasis mine):

> ### Return Values
>
> Returns the number of bytes read from the file. If an error occurs,
>   FALSE is returned and unless the function was called as @readfile(),
>   **an error message is printed**.

The reference to `@` is not even particularly correct because you can have a custom error handler that ignores it. That means that, depending on your server configuration, you can have the URL printed as part of the output. For example, running your code as-is prints this in my computer:

> `Warning: readfile(http://example.com/files/download/file.pdf): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found  in
>   Standard input code on line 13`

This (and similar issues) can be avoided by ensuring that error messages are never shown to user. That typically involves setting `display_errors` to `false` in production environment and, in cases like this, ensuring that the warning is properly handled (either with `@` or with a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)).

In any case, protected downloads are normally handled with password-protected locations and/or temporary links. A proxy server doesn't hide the fact that there's an open internet server where the file can be freely downloaded.

---

**Note:** This answer was written under the assumption that network downloads were being used because it was a remote resource. Using HTTP to fetch a local file is the equivalent of sharing your desktop on the internet to open files with Google Chrome instead of double-clicking on the file manager. The proper way to build a protected download system is to move the files outside the public web server root and feeding `readfile()` with the local file system path, e.g.:

```
readfile('/home/foo/private/file.pdf');
```

This way, accidentally revealing the local path is not a security issue. But, as said, that's a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using Wordpress to manage it. I want to add htaccess "Deny from all" to that directory and use form to force download. But if I use htaccess above, it returns a wrong file can be opened with Notepad with content is "314 linkfile.pdf". Any suggestion for me?

Comment: What role does `Deny from all` play here? Do you mean that your server is not protected either?

Comment: `Deny from all` will not allow someone browse/download file from known url (http://example.com/files/download/file.pdf). It is right?

Comment: If you don't add exceptions, it won't allow anyone. I'm getting confused... How many servers are involved here?

Comment: Thank you but how to add exception for htaccess? I am ready to check your answer as a best. Can you help me this? Thank you so much.

Comment: The `http://example.com` part was a red herring, wasn't it? In fact, you only have one server and you use `http://example.com/files/download/file.pdf` to grab a local file, don't you?

Comment: Yes. I have only one to grab a local file.